# QLabel sizehint is too small

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a QAbstractItemDelegate and in the paint method, I am trying to paint the text from a label. But the problem I am seeing is that the size hint of the QLabel is always too small for the text it contains. How can I fix this? For example:

```
QLabel *testlabel = new QLabel();
testlabel->setText("This is some test text that doesnt fit:");
testlabel->adjustSize();

QRect rect(testlabel->geometry());
Qt::Alignment alignFlags = testlabel->alignment();

painter->setFont(testlabel->font());
painter->drawRect(rect);
painter->drawText(rect, alignFlags, testlabel->text());
```

And then it looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas why the bounding rectangle is too small?
Thanks
Stephen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are just trying to draw a bounding rectangle (or something related), you should get the  painter's font metrics and ask for a bounding rectangle for the text you want to display. There are different versions of [QFontMetrics::boundingRect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#boundingRect) that will allow you to specify a containing rectangle so word wrapping will be taken into consideration.

Comment: Worked a treat, thank you! I still would like to know however why the rectangle from QLabel is too small for it's text?

Comment: It would likely be because the QLabel you create inside that function never gets to arrange itself until your paint function exits and returns control to the event loop at which point "update" processing can occur for the label.

Comment: you can use `void QCoreApplication::processEvents ( QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlags flags = QEventLoop::AllEvents ) [static]` or `void QCoreApplication::processEvents ( QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlags flags, int maxtime ) [static]` to process the qlabel's update event, which is needed to calculate size

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use `virtual QSize QLabel::sizeHint () const` for getting the sizehint? it seems to be more reliable, because `adjustSize();geometry()` depends on the label being actually drawn onto something. but you don't draw the label (QWidget), but only it's text (QString), so `adjustSize/geometry` are more likely to fail than `sizeHint`.

see: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop

EDIT: oh, and using `sizeHint` would also simplify your code...

Comment: The width that sizeHint() gives me is the same as the width from geometry().

Comment: oh, then maybe you should look at QLabel's sources to see how it's drawn there. oh, and why can't you simply call the label's paint method? would be best imao...