# How to reimplement sizeHint for bold text in a delegate? (Qt)

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

**Short Version**

Running `resizeColumnsToContents` works fine for regular text, but when I change text to bold, the columns are too narrow. How can I fix `sizeHint` in my custom delegate to take into account that my text is bold?

**Details**

I am using a custom delegate to make the text in a column bold. To do this, in the paint method of the delegate, in the column of interest I just run `option.font.setWeight(QtGui.QFont.Bold)`.

When resizing columns to contents, however, the column with bolded text is too narrow. I tried to reimplement `sizeHint` in the delegate as follows, but it yields columns that are the exact same size as the default implementation:

```
def sizeHint(self, option, index):
    fontMetrics = option.fontMetrics  
    if index.column() == 0:
        text = index.model().data(index)
        document = QtGui.QTextDocument(text)
        document.setDefaultFont(option.font)
        return QtCore.QSize(document.idealWidth(), fontMetrics.height())
    return QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.sizeHint(self, option, index)
```

So, how can I get the `sizeHint` to correctly identify the width of my emboldened font? It seems I am simply sending in plain text here.

**Related Questions**

[QLabel sizehint is too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680047/qlabel-sizehint-is-too-small)

Comment: Create new font object initialized with **option.font**. Make it bold. Create new fontMetrics object and initialize it with newly created emboldened font and then calculate width for existing text (**QFontMetrics::width( QString, int )**).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comment by Pie_Jesu, I inserted `option.font.setWeight(QtGui.QFont.Bold)` before calculating the width. So `sizeHint` ends up as follows:

```
def sizeHint(self, option, index):
    fontMetrics = option.fontMetrics  
    if index.column() == 0:
        text = index.model().data(index)
        document = QtGui.QTextDocument(text)
        option.font.setWeight(QtGui.QFont.Bold) #new line
        document.setDefaultFont(option.font)
        return QtCore.QSize(document.idealWidth(), fontMetrics.height())
    return QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.sizeHint(self, option, index)
```

So, basically, whatever properties you set with the text in your `paint` function, one way to match that width within `sizeHint` would be to explicitly build in those same properties.

It works, but it seems like suspicious code reduplication to set the text properties twice, once in `paint` and then again in `sizeHint`. There should be a more modular way. That is, a way for `sizeHint` to directly *read* the formatting from the item being displayed.

Edit added later: that's pretty much how these things work. On the plus size, by using `QTextDocument`, you are only setting up a document, not attaching it to a `QTextEdit` for display, so there is actually not much overhead here.